# Why does my app "unfortunately stop". All this I want is some simple buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my very first app. All I need is five buttons, two that call certain phone numbers (only have created one so far) and three buttons that take the user to a certain URL. I have no errors or warnings or any direction on how to navigate the LogCat.

LogCat:

```
10-08 14:41:40.716: D/AndroidRuntime(793): Shutting down VM
10-08 14:41:40.716: W/dalvikvm(793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{acps.mhs/acps.mhs.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at acps.mhs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-08 14:41:40.777: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  ... 11 more
10-08 14:42:19.696: I/Process(793): Sending signal. PID: 793 SIG: 9
```

Mainactivity.java

```
package acps.mhs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button mhshome, pp, mhsdir, cmhs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);


        mhshome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mhshome);
        pp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pp);
        mhsdir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mhsdir);
        cmhs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmhs);

        mhshome.setOnClickListener(this);
        pp.setOnClickListener(this);
        mhsdir.setOnClickListener(this);
        cmhs.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()) {

       case R.id.mhshome:
             Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www2.k12albemarle.org/school/mohs/Pages/default.aspx");
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
             startActivity(intent);
           break;


       case R.id.pp:
             Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("http://www2.k12albemarle.org/school/MOHS/Pages/Directory.aspx");
             Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
             startActivity(intent2);
           break; 

       case R.id.mhsdir:
             Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("http://www2.k12albemarle.org/school/MOHS/Pages/Directory.aspx");
             Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
             startActivity(intent3);
               break;

       case R.id.cmhs:
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
               break;
   }
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pp"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mhshome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/pp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mhshome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/mhshome" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mhsdir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/mhsdir" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mhsdir"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/callmhs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Its gonna be something incredibly simple I'm certain. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Read the error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at acps.mhs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` :) That's why `findViewById` is returning null on your views.

Comment: It is saying my layout cannot be resolved to a variable. Why is this happening? What should I do?

Comment: You should use R.layout.activity_main...the part after "layout." is just whatever the name of your XML file is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting your layout.

Call `setContentView(layout)` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: And make sure you call it **before** you try to `findViewById` anything.